# UI automation: export element tree

Tags: instruments, ios-ui-automation

In UI automation, is there a way to export the element tree generated by `logElementTree()` in a format different than the default (eg. XML). I would like to use the element hierarchy outside of UI automation.

I have logged the tree using `logElementTree()` in a test script and it succeeds, showing in the Editor log as "passed". I have tried to "Export Traced Results" but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Appium inspector to get the XML result: [Appium](https://github.com/appium/appium-dot-app)

Appium is an open source automation framework. It also provides tools to get app UI hierarchy.

Follow the instructions and launch Appium inspector. Fill the required information such as device type and UDID. Screenshot: [Appium Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Boriq.png)

Use Appium GUI and there's a "copy XML" button on the bottom-right corner. Press refresh button to get the UI hierarchy of the current screen.

Here's the result of the calculator app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AppiumAUT>
    <UIAApplication name="Calculator" label="Calculator" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0" x="0" y="20" width="320" height="548">
        <UIAWindow name="" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0" x="0" y="0" width="320" height="568">
            <UIAStaticText name="Result" label="Result" value="0" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/0" x="0" y="0" width="320" height="168">
            </UIAStaticText>
            <UIAButton name="all clear" label="all clear" value="all clear" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/1" x="1.5" y="169.5" width="78.5" height="79">
            </UIAButton>
            <UIAButton name="plus, minus" label="plus, minus" value="plus, minus" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/2" x="80.5" y="169.5" width="79" height="79">
            </UIAButton>
            <UIAButton name="percent" label="percent" value="percent" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/3" x="160" y="169.5" width="79" height="79">
            </UIAButton>
            <UIAButton name="divide" label="divide" value="divide" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/4" x="239.5" y="169.5" width="79" height="79">
            </UIAButton>
            <UIAButton name="7" label="7" value="7" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/5" x="1.5" y="249" width="78.5" height="79">
            </UIAButton>
            <UIAButton name="8" label="8" value="8" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/6" x="80.5" y="249" width="79" height="79">
            </UIAButton>
            <UIAButton name="9" label="9" value="9" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/7" x="160" y="249" width="79" height="79">
            </UIAButton>
            <UIAButton name="multiply" label="multiply" value="multiply" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/8" x="239.5" y="249" width="79" height="79">
            </UIAButton>
            <UIAButton name="4" label="4" value="4" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/9" x="1.5" y="328.5" width="78.5" height="79">
            </UIAButton>
            <UIAButton name="5" label="5" value="5" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/10" x="80.5" y="328.5" width="79" height="79">
            </UIAButton>
            <UIAButton name="6" label="6" value="6" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/11" x="160" y="328.5" width="79" height="79">
            </UIAButton>
            <UIAButton name="subtract" label="subtract" value="subtract" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/12" x="239.5" y="328.5" width="79" height="79">
            </UIAButton>
            <UIAButton name="1" label="1" value="1" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/13" x="1.5" y="408" width="78.5" height="79">
            </UIAButton>
            <UIAButton name="2" label="2" value="2" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/14" x="80.5" y="408" width="79" height="79">
            </UIAButton>
            <UIAButton name="3" label="3" value="3" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/15" x="160" y="408" width="79" height="79">
            </UIAButton>
            <UIAButton name="add" label="add" value="add" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/16" x="239.5" y="408" width="79" height="79">
            </UIAButton>
            <UIAButton name="0" label="0" value="0" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/17" x="1.5" y="487.5" width="157" height="79">
            </UIAButton>
            <UIAButton name="decimal" label="decimal" value="decimal" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/18" x="160" y="487.5" width="79" height="79">
            </UIAButton>
            <UIAButton name="equals" label="equals" value="equals" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/19" x="239.5" y="487.5" width="79" height="79">
            </UIAButton>
        </UIAWindow>
        <UIAWindow name="" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/1" x="0" y="0" width="320" height="568">
            <UIAStatusBar name="" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/1/0" x="0" y="0" width="320" height="20">
                <UIAElement name="2 of 5 bars, signal strength" label="2 of 5 bars, signal strength" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="Swipe down with three fingers to reveal the notification center., Swipe up with three fingers to reveal the control center, Double-tap to scroll to top" path="/0/1/0/0" x="6" y="0" width="35" height="20">
                </UIAElement>
                <UIAElement name="T-Mobile network" label="T-Mobile network" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="Swipe down with three fingers to reveal the notification center., Swipe up with three fingers to reveal the control center, Double-tap to scroll to top" path="/0/1/0/1" x="44" y="0" width="48" height="20">
                </UIAElement>
                <UIAElement name="3 of 3 Wi-Fi bars" label="3 of 3 Wi-Fi bars" value="FireEye" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="Swipe down with three fingers to reveal the notification center., Swipe up with three fingers to reveal the control center, Double-tap to scroll to top" path="/0/1/0/2" x="97" y="0" width="13" height="20">
                </UIAElement>
                <UIAElement name="10:48 AM" label="10:48 AM" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="Swipe down with three fingers to reveal the notification center., Swipe up with three fingers to reveal the control center, Double-tap to scroll to top" path="/0/1/0/3" x="134" y="0" width="52" height="20">
                </UIAElement>
                <UIAElement name="95% battery power, Charging" label="95% battery power, Charging" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="Swipe down with three fingers to reveal the notification center., Swipe up with three fingers to reveal the control center, Double-tap to scroll to top" path="/0/1/0/4" x="282" y="0" width="33" height="20">
                </UIAElement>
            </UIAStatusBar>
        </UIAWindow>
    </UIAApplication>
</AppiumAUT>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I edited my answer. Please suggest if there's anything I can improve.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp

Would something like the above work?

For example something like this would roughly parse the results of the test into an HTML table:

```
<table border="1" style="width:800px">
                    <tr>
                    <th>Timestammp</th>
                    <th>Sequence</th>
                    <th>Message</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Screenshot</th>
                    </tr>
<xsl:for-each select="plist/dict/array/dict">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="translate(translate(date, 'T',' '), 'Z','')"/>
                            </td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="string"/></td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="integer = 8"><span style="color:blue">Screenshot</span></xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:when test="integer = 5"><span style="color:green">Pass</span></xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:when test="integer = 4"><span style="color:orange">Message</span></xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="integer"/></xsl:otherwise>
                                </xsl:choose>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:if test="integer = 8">
                                    <xsl:element name="img">
                                        <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="string"/>.png</xsl:attribute>
                                        <xsl:attribute name="style">height:250px;width:167px;</xsl:attribute>
                                    </xsl:element>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
```

Just as a note it has been a while since I've used this because I'm not at that point in my project yet and I believe most of it came from someone's blog. If I can find the site again I'll post the credit for it.